# How to pass session variable into a form in PHP?

Tags: php, session, echo

I currently have this code but it is not display the u_mail

```
if (isset($_SESSION['u_email'])) {
echo "<form method='POST' action='".setComments($connComment)."'>
<input type='hidden' name='uid' value='$_SESSION['u_email']'>
</form>" } 
getComments($conn)
```

How do I display it?

I tried testing it by doing:

```
<?php
 echo $_SESSION['u_email'];
 ?>
```

And it works completely fine. It is just when I put it in an echo. I actually SHOULD put it in echo. Is there a way in PHP to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: You forget `"` in `<input type='hidden' name='uid' value='".$_SESSION['u_email']."'>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just break out from the string and concatenate, like this:

```
echo "<form method='POST' action='".setComments($connComment)."'>
<input type='hidden' name='uid' value='" . $_SESSION['u_email'] ."'>
</form>";
```

Comment: nice. fast reply i give up haha